# Is $C^\omega([0,1])$ normable? (And about the growth of coefficients of infinitely differentiable functions)

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

This question arised to me when trying to prove that the space of infinitely differentiable functions defined in a compact space $K\subset\mathbb{C}$ taking values in $\mathbb{C}$, that is $C^\infty(K)$, is a Banach space.
It is well known that $C^n(K)$ (the space of n-times continuously diferentiable functions) is a Banach space with the norm
$$||f||:=||f||_\infty+...+||f^{n)}||_\infty$$
When I try to define an analogous norm for $C^\infty(K)$, I have the problem that I dont know how fast is allowed to grow the sequence
$$(||f^{n)}||_\infty)_n$$
I've read from several sources that $C^\infty(K)$ is a Frechet space so I'm guessing that there is no restriction about the growth of that sequence. Its that true?
Any help would be appreciated.

(Update) [$\approx$ Solved] I've read that the space of analytic functions $C^\omega([0,1])$ is not normable (nor $C^\infty([0,1])$ either then), so my question must have a negative answer: If it were true that $||f^{n)}||_\infty\leq M_n$ for some absolute (i.e. holding for every $f\in C^\omega([0,1])$) sequence $(M_n)_n$ of positive numbers, then we could define
$$||f||_\omega:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n}\frac{||f^{n)}||_\infty}{M_n}$$
for $f\in C^\omega([0,1])$. It is inmediate to verify that $||\cdot||_\omega$ (would) define a norm over $C^\omega([0,1])$. As this can't happen, there is not such sequence $(M_n)_n$.

[I guess that saying that $C^\omega([0,1])$ is not normable means with respect to the topology "where $f$ and $g$ are close if $f^{n)}$ and $g^{n)}$ are close for every $n\geq0$". That is, with respect to the topology $\tau$ generated by $\{B(\varepsilon,f)\}_{\varepsilon>0,f\in C^\omega([0,1])}$, where $B(\varepsilon,f)=\{g\in C^\omega([0,1]):||g^{n)}-f^{n)}||_\infty<\varepsilon\ \forall n\geq0\}$]

As proving that $C^\omega([0,1])$ is  not normable with respect to $\tau$ is the only remaining question, I've changed the tittle.
Again, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Interesting question. The obvious functions I can think of are of the form $f(x)=\sum x^nf^{(n)}(0)/n! $ on $[0,1]$, where $\Vert f^{(n)}\Vert_\infty$ is reached at $0$, and thus $\Vert f^{(n)}\Vert_\infty \in O(r^{-n}n!)$ for some $r>0$. I'm pretty sure that there are functions where the sequence grows even faster.

Answer (score 1):

Take any exponential on $[0,1]$ for instance $f : x\rightarrow e^{2x}$.

$f^{(n)}(x)=2^nf(x)$, so $\Vert f^{(n)}\Vert=2^ne\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: Ok, so it can grow exponentially. But it is as fast as we can get? I mean, if I define $||f||:=\sum_{n=O}^\infty\frac{||f^{n)}||_\infty}{n!}$ then it is true that $||f||<\infty$ for every $f\in C^\infty(K)$?. For your example it is $||f||=e^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Given a numerical sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ there exists a compactly supported $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ function $f$ such that 
$$
\frac{d^n f}{dx^n}(0)=a_n.$$ 
This is (a simplification of) a result of Borel. It is Theorem 1.2.6 of Hörmander's book "The Analysis of Partial Differential Operators", vol. 1.

This shows that the derivatives of $C^\infty$ functions can grow arbitrarily fast, so putting a norm on $C^\infty$ is hopeless.

Concerning *analytic* functions, I don't know. And seeing the post dates, I don't know either if there still is somebody interested.